# return elements starting from the beginning of the array until a number is hit that is less than its position in the array?

Tags: arrays, linq-to-sql

The following code is producing the error

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'int' because it is not a delegate type.
```

My code:

```
public void test()  { 
    int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };      
    var firstSmallNumbers = numbers.Take((n, index) => n >= index); 
    Console.WriteLine("First numbers not less than their position:"); 
    foreach (var n in firstSmallNumbers) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(n); 
    }    
}
```

**Question**

How can I stop the error being produced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use TakeWhile instead of only Take

Comment: Thank you very much